# Assembler Intelx86: Comparing if I'm at the end of a string isn't working

Tags: string, assembly, x86, intel

I was doing a program in Assembler for Intelx86 (32 Bits, writing in Windows) where I have to cipher a string that I receive with _gets. I cipher by blocks of two chars, and if those two are the same, I need to add them to the Result String without having to change them. To iterate through the string I use EBX, like this:

```
cmp byte[userstring + ebx], 0
je EmptyBlock
```

For some reason, it works when it's only two characters, but when the string has 4 characters (All being exactly the same, ex "AAAA") it stops working. It enters an endless loop with the EBX increasing by 2 nonstop. Am I skipping something? Am I doing the wrong comparison? Sorry, I'm new to Assembler.

Comment: Are you sure your string is really 0-terminated?  Use a debugger to examine memory (and registers as you single-step.)  Yes, `cmp byte [...], 0` / `je` is one valid way to branch on a byte in memory being zero, so that's not the problem and your question is missing an [mcve].

Comment: How would I know if something I receive with _gets is -0 terminated? Besides, It works when it's an empty string, or 2 characters. But it doesn't work for more than that. There's another case with the same problem, if a block only has one character (That being if you have "ABC" or "ABCDE", "C" and "E" being these characters), I have to do another case. It works for 1 and 3, but it stops working for 5 or more. I don't know why it suddenly stops working. Fortunately, I decided to use EDX to count all the characters in the string, getting the length, and comparing with that.

Comment: By looking at the bytes in memory and finding a `0` byte after the expected number of characters.  If you overwrote the end of you buffer with something else before this code runs, it might not still be there.  ISO C `gets` *always* appends a `'\0'` byte; it doesn't check lengths or even have an arg for buffer size so it always behaves the same; there's no way it can decide that the buffer didn't have room for a `0`.  If Windows `_gets` is the same, then your string is always 0-terminated to start with.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Assembly x86: LEA and MOVSB changes my Source String?](//stackoverflow.com/q/59122864) (which probably should have been an edit to this)

Comment: You say it is increasing EBX by 2 nonstop?  Why 2?  Characters are only 1 byte long.   Why not show more code -- two instructions (and no data) is not really enough to say what is going on with your loop.

Comment: Yes, I should have gone more into detail. Anyway, the problem is over, I had to use other alternatives. 
I had to cipher a string by blocks of two characters, and put the ciphed characters in a result string. I used EBX to iterate through both strings, not by characters, but by blocks. That's why it's 2 and not 1. It worked for the first time, when I was seeing if the received string was valid using EDX, but when I wanted to iterate it a second time, the exact same way, it didn't stop looping.
I ended up storing the value of EDX, which had the length of said string, and compared EBX to that.